# Можно ли на этапе компиляции отличить statement от expression?

Tags: c++

#### Вступление

**Expression:**
An expression is a sequence of operators and their operands, that specifies a computation.

(Выражение - это последовательность операторов и их операндов, которая задает вычисление.)

[Ссылка.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions)

**Statement:** Statements are fragments of the C++ program that are executed in sequence. The body of any function is a sequence of statements.

(Инструкции - это фрагменты программы на C++, которые выполняются последовательно. Тело любой функции представляет собой последовательность операторов.)

[Ссылка.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/statements)

#### Теперь о главном

Я пишу макрос, который проверяет, что код внутри макроса выбросил какое-то исключение

```
#define EXPECT_THROW(statement) ...
```

Этот макрос может принимать выражения или инструкции

```
// Функция с nodiscard.
[[nodiscard]] int get_int(){
    return {};
}

// Функция, которая возвращает void.
void get_void(){
}

struct foo{
  foo(int a){
  }
};

int main(){
    EXPECT_THROW(get_int());   // Проверка, что вызов функции бросает исключение.
    EXPECT_THROW(get_void());  // Проверка, что вызов функции (которая ничего не возвращает) бросает исключение.
    EXPECT_THROW(foo f = foo(1));  // Проверка, что выражение бросает исключение.
}
```

Макрос уже написан, но есть одна проблема:

Если я проверяю функцию, которая помечена как `[[nodiscard]]`, то получаю предупреждение

```
Предупреждение  C4834   отмена возвращаемого значения функции с атрибутом "nodiscard"
```

Я придумал, как избежать предупреждение, но делается это вручную:

```
// Пусть простейшая реализация для компиляции будет такой
#define EXPECT_THROW(statement) {statement;}

int main(){
    // EXPECT_THROW(get_int());             // Было так
    // Можно решить проблему 2 способами
    EXPECT_THROW(auto const _ = get_int()); // Сохранить значение во временную переменную.
    EXPECT_THROW((void)get_int());          // Привести значение к void.

    // EXPECT_THROW(get_void());     // Было так
    // Тут нет проблемы, но можно применить 2 способа
    EXPECT_THROW(get_void());        // Ничего не делать
    EXPECT_THROW((void)get_void());  // Привести к void

    // Тут нет проблемы и нельзя применить ни один из способов
    EXPECT_THROW(foo f = foo(1));
}
```

Теперь хочется переписать макрос так, чтобы он автоматически приводил тип к `void`, если `statement` что-то возвращает.

Для этого я бы определил макрос вот так:

```
#define EXPECT_THROW(statement) (void)(statement)
```

Но это не работает для инструкций:

```
EXPECT_THROW(foo f = foo(1));
EXPECT_THROW(int a = 1);
```

Получается, что мне нужно отличать этот случай и обрабатывать его без приведения к `void`, но я не знаю,  как это можно сделать.

Отсюда и вопрос: **можно ли как-то отличить statement от expression?**

Чтобы можно было реализовать макрос как-то так:

```
#define EXPECT_THROW(statement)                   \
  if constexpr(is_expression(statement)) {        \
    (void)(statement);                            \
  } else if constexpr(is_statement(statement)) {  \
    /* nothing */                                 \
  }
```

### Дополнение

В google test есть макрос `EXPECT_THROW`, который выдает предупреждение на все функции объявленные с `nodiscard`.

Поэтому я хотел переопределить свой макрос, который бы не выдавал предупреждений

```
#define MY_EXPECT_THROW(statement)  EXPECT_THROW((void)statement)
```

Но это не работает для некоторых случаев.

Comment: При таком прочтении вопроса на русском получается ерунда. *Выражение — это последовательность операторов и...*, *Операторы - это фрагменты программы на C++, которые...* Может, лучше переводить Statements как инструкции?

Comment: Это все очень похоже на проблему XY. В С++ нет никаких средств, позволяющих определить, могут ли на каком-то участке кода возникать исключения или нет. А если это какой-то тест при выполнении на перехват выброшенного наружу исключения, то макрос не нужен, достаточно будет сделать перехват всех исключений через `catch (...)`

Comment: Я добавил дополнение, чтобы было понятнее, что за проблема у меня.

Comment: Компиляторо-зависимыми `_Pragma`-ми выключить нужный ворнинг внутри макроса, потом включить обратно...

Answer (score 2):

Как выяснилось, проблема заключалась в том, что макрос `EXPECT_THROW` из google test выдает предупреждение на все функции объявленные с `nodiscard`.

Правильным решением в этом случае является отказ от использования макроса `EXPECT_THROW` и перевод выброшенных исключений в выходные данные теста. Это также полезно, так как обычно надо проверять не просто то, что исключение было выброшено, но еще и его содержимое, что невозможно с `EXPECT_THROW`. Ну и можно без проблем поставить точку останова в тестируемый код.

```
::std::size_t runtime_errors_count{};
::std::string err_message{};
try
{
    // тут тестируемый код
}
catch (::std::runtime_error const & exception)
{
    ++runtime_errors_count;
    err_message.append(exception.what());
}
EXPECT_EQ(::std::size_t{1} == runtime_errors_count);
EXPECT_EQ(::std::string("total fail") == err_message);
```